# Subsonic connections and dataset

Tags: subsonic

If using subsonic, i know you hav to close a datareader. but what if you get a dataset back, from a stored procedure? What can you close?
So if its like this -

```
 SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = SubSonic.StoredProcedure; 
 DataSet ds = DataSet; 
 ds = sp.GetDataSet;
```

What do i close when done? I don't think dataset can be closed, right? This is Subsonic 2.x

Sorry if this was posted already, i tried to post earlier but got error message, and then couldnt find it so am trying again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is made when the sproc is executed. After it makes the connect and pulls the data in to the dataset object the connection is automatically closed by SubSonic. No need to close anything manually.